# How to Connect SQlite Studio Database with Python SQLite3 Module?

Tags: python, sqlite

I downloaded a GUI SQL database management software called SQLite Studio. The database that I created in that program is of the SQLite3 version. Now I have a problem when I try to connect to that database using python (MY IDE PyCharm). I don't understand what I am doing wrong? Clearly the database that has been created in SQLite Studio is there with some tables and values, but I can't connect it with python.

I created a database called, 'test' and the table called UserInfo on SQLite Studio...

I am sure my code is right, but if anyone can help that would be great.

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db') #  I have tried: test, test.db, etc....
c = db.cursor()

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM UserInfo'):
    print(row)
```

I get the error no such table, even when it clearly exists in my Studio program. So knowing Python. Since it could not find that database it created a new instance of a database and also called test.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to use the absolute path of the db created through the gui. also, you're missing the closing quote in your query `'SELECT * FROM UserInfo`

Comment: Sorry typo on the format.

Comment: Also there isn't an absolute path to the database.

Comment: locate your created `test.db` file and place it in the current working directory. Here it is not able to find your created `test.db` so is creating a new `test.db` file which obviously will not have your created tables. place your `test.db` in the folder where you created your project.

Comment: Yea not really the solution I was looking for, but I managed to get it to work by creating the db in python then looking for the file in Studio. For some reason though, it doesn't work the other way.

Comment: create db in sqlite3 and locate that file. Your db file needs to be in your python project directory because, the directory structure outside it is not accessible directly.